# Substring for thai language

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am facing a very interesting problem.
following is the string from which i want to take sub string.

```
  1¨Ñ§ËÇÑ´1xxxxxxxx
```

index 0-2 (length 3) is the Province ID
index 3-35 (length 32) is the province name in thai.

when i try to take sub string province like following

```
string line = "1¨Ñ§ËÇÑ´1xxxxxxxx                ";
line.Substring(3,32).Trim();
```

This shows me error as following

```
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
```

Keep in mind that when i debug the code line total length shows me 33 which should be 35. and province sub string is shown 30.

Following is the code...

```
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("File06.txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(".................. Content of " + file.Name + "..............");
            string codeOfProvince, nameOfProvince, line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                codeOfProvince = line.Substring(0, 3).Trim();
                nameOfProvince = line.Substring(3,32).Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("codeOfProvince {0}, nameOfProvince {1}", codeOfProvince , nameOfProvince );
            }
            Console.WriteLine("..............................................................");
            Console.WriteLine();
```

I'm sure this will help you out and the file has following data

```
  1¨Ñ§ËÇÑ´1xxxxxxxx                
  2¨Ñ§ËÇÑ´2xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The length of the whole string is 33. You are doing `Substring(3, 32)` which would take it beyond 33 characters, hence the error.

Comment: Can't you use `Substring(3)` to get everything up to the end?

Comment: But when i count i in the string which i give it has 35 length. Just watch how many characters are there in "1¨Ñ§ËÇÑ´1xxxxxxxx                ". where i declared the string.

Comment: 33 is the number of characters that is shown when debugged. but in real there is 35 characters. Why VS is missing 2 characters. Try two run this code in VS.

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? Where _does_ it contain 35 characters? How do you get it into your application?

Comment: I am reading a file line by line which contain a record like this...
`"  1¨Ñ§ËÇÑ´1xxxxxxxx                "`
Please checkout the characters in above string.

Comment: That's what I thought. What encoding is the file written in? What encoding are you reading the file with? They should both be the same.

Comment: Sorry stack overflow doesn't allow me to show white spaces...

Comment: How are you reading the file? Are you using `Trim` at all? Please post your code.

Comment: ok i'm editing and pasting my code in question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i got the answer. I was reading file with ANSI encoding. When i changed the file to UNICODE Encoding it started working.

Comment: I was going to say that while I don't speak Thai, `"1¨Ñ§ËÇÑ´1xxxxxxxx" ` doesn't look like valid Thai to me, and that you were reading the file with an incorrect encoding.